# Even though Github pages is static, can I make a domain availability lookup site?

Tags: domains, github, availability

I am building a website to be hosted on Github.

The documentation says Github pages is for static websites. Will I be able build a feature on the website that allows others to look up domain availability?

Comment: Static site means things render on browser side. You can use Javascript on your github pages, which is also render on browser side. And Javascript can do lot's of stuff. You can use third party API on your script to make it happens. [Checkout this site for example](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should write it thus all work is done on client side (JavaScript). And that way you should use external services to check for availability.